# PL/SQL Developer - Show outline statement block

Tags: plsqldeveloper

As i can do in Visual Studio, I want to see outline statement block in PL/SQL Developer like that (red line) :

[image]

I don't find any plugin/trick for that, an idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found such a feature. To help myself I'm copying code into Notepad++ to see the outlines if I need it - but of course it's only temporary solution.